# Create calendardateselect from javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, xhtml, prototype

Not sure why I can't figure this out. When a user makes a selection, a javascript method is called, at which point I want to add a calendardateselect to an existing div tag from the javascript.

According to the docs, it seems like this should work:

```
var a = new CalendarDateSelect( document.getElementById("date_area"), {embedded:true, year_range:10} );
$('date_area').insert(a);
```

... or maybe this....

```
var newScript   = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type  = 'text/javascript';
var tn      = document.createTextNode("new CalendarDateSelect( $(this).previous() )");
newScript.appendChild(tn);
$('date_area').insert(newScript);
```

http://code.google.com/p/calendardateselect/wiki/JavascriptDocumentation

But neither of them are working. I feel like I've tried everything.
Ideas?

Comment: Why are you creating a `<script>` tag and adding an `[object]` text node to it?

Comment: Because I tried this and it didn't work either:
var a = new CalendarDateSelect( $(this).previous() );
$('date_area').insert(a);
I was trying to add the contents of the script tag by creating the textNode

Comment: You're doing it completely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the first try works:

```
var a = new CalendarDateSelect( document.getElementById("date_area"), {embedded:true, year_range:10} );
$('date_area').insert(a);
```

But the trick was that CalendarDateSelect seems to rely on having a hidden input field in the div where this is created. Once I added that, the above code worked perfectly.

But a better way is simply:

```
new CalendarDateSelect(
    $('date_area'),
    {
       embedded:   true,
       year_range: 10
   }
);
```